# Trouble starting C++ Program

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, executable

I have a C++-Makefile Project that I built and linked and everything went fine.

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /folder/build/
```

First I used the bash to configure the project with cmake, then I loaded the project as "existing makefileproject" in eclipse and built it. Building went fine too but than I try to run the program and I get an error:

```
Error starting process.
Exec_tty error:Cannot run program "/folder/build/programname": Unknown reason
Exec_tty error:Cannot run program "/folder/build/programname": Unknown reason
Exec_tty error:Cannot run program "/folder/build/programname": Unknown reason
```

I tried to run the project from the bash as well but the resulting error message was:

```
If 'programname' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf programname
```

I used `ls -l programname` to get information about the file.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 username users 6411620 Apr 27 13:54 programname
```

when I try to change the read and write modus with

```
chmod 777 programname
```

nothing happens and programnames information stays the same.

What went wrong with my building of the project?

Comment: Are you saying that the chmod 777 programname failed (e.g. did not change permissions to rwxrwxrwx)?  If so, there could be a security policy in place preventing the change (it is not a good idea security wise to have a program that everyone can run).  If this is the case, try one of these instead 'chmod 744 programname' or 'chmod 764 programname'.  These will set so only you can run it, or only you and your group can run it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to try:

- Try a simple program (e.g. hello world) to make sure your environment is set up correctly.  If you do hello world, make sure you put a `sleep(5);` statement or something similar so it will stay on the screen long enough to see it.
- Try to build the program in Eclipse, and let it generate the make file for you.
- Make sure your permissions are set correctly (which you were doing with chmod), but do another ls -l to ensure your permission changes were effective.  I would suggest `chmod 760 programname` to be more in compliance with security policies.
- To run your program in Linux, you can cd to the directory that contains the program, and type `./programname`

Hopefully one of these will work for you!

Comment: okay, I tried hello world. It could be built but when I try to run it I have the same error as with my "programname" project. I get the makefile and everything but cant run the program. Besides I cant change the permissions with chmod. Neither from my "programname" nor from my "helloworld" project. permissions stays -rw-r--r--

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you at least need execute permissions.  You will at the very least need -rwx------ and will possibly need up to -rwxrwx---.  Will it let you do chmod 774, or chmod 744?

Comment: You will probably need to speak with your system administrator and explain that you aren't able to change the permissions as required for your program.  It needs the execute permission (x) to run.  Hopefully he/she can help you.

Comment: Yeah.. actually, as I'm using my own laptop, the "administrator" might be me (;

Comment: In that case, you should be able to log in as root and run the chmod command (although that would not be a permanent fix).  You can also try `chmod u+x programname` as this would be the least likely to be blocked by security policy, and should accomplish what you need.  It is possible you will also need group permission to execute, and in that case, also do `chmod g+x programname`

Comment: I tried it with the hollo world project. I tried "chmod u+x hello" and chmod g+x hello - nothing happened. Then I logged in as root with "su" and tried the same - no change! /:

Comment: btw I have a virtual box opensuse 64bit and Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Comment: okay, now I tried the following: my eclipse workspace is on an USB-stick. I copied the executable to my homefolder and changed the permissions with "chmod u+x programname" - permissions have been changed and I could run the programm. I tried to copy the exequtable back to the USB-stick but then the permissions changed again. might it be that it is not possible to run a programm vfrom an USB-stick?

Comment: hmm, might be something to do with having it on a USB stick, I have never tried that or encountered that problem.  I would suggest working off your hard drive.